# How do I estimate the p-value for the null hypothesis that these two sets of values have the same probability of falling within a specific range?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, t-test

The two sets of values are:

`LCp = c(2.17, 2.57, 1.11, 1.92, 2.41, 1.44, 2.51, 1.69, 2.00, 1.20, NA, 4.46, 1.43, 1.86, 2.93, 1.17, 1.48, 2.86, 2.57, 3.53, 1.96, 1.57, 1.05, NA, 4.94, 1.72)
HCp = c(2.76, 5.06, 2.51, 3.31, 4.19, 3.93, 4.82, 3.04, 2.72, 1.81, 3.41, 6.83, 2.89, 3.42, 4.34, 1.69, 2.45, 2.67, 3.82, 4.19, 2.97, 2.98, 1.75, NA, 8.72, NA)`

Since they are assumed to be **log-normally distributed**, the $ln$ transformation is applied:

`ln_LCp = log(LCp)
ln_HCp = log(HCp)`

I want to test if their probabilities of falling within 1 and 4 are significantly different. Is there any proper way of doing so, using hypothesis testing **only once**?

My current thought:

> For each set of values (after taking $ln$; *NA* are omitted),
>
> 1. Calculate $\mu$, $SE_\mu$, $\sigma^2$ and $SE_{\sigma^2}$ (calculated as $\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma^4}{N-1}}$).
> 2. Simulate 10,000 sets of $\bar{x} \sim N(\mu, {SE_\mu}^2)$, $s\sim \sqrt{N(\sigma^2, {SE_{\sigma^2}}^2)}$ ($s$ was sampled until positive).
> 3. For each set of $(\bar{x}, s)$, calculate $P(1 \sim 4)=P(\frac{ln(1)-\bar{x}}{s}\le z \le \frac{ln(4)-\bar{x}}{s})$.
> 4. 10,000 $P(1 \sim 4)$ values have been obtained.
>
> Then compare the two sets of $P(1 \sim 4)$ values by a two independent sample *t*-test.

The problem is $P(1 \sim 4)$ does not seem to be normally distributed for me.

I feel like I am complicating the problem but I could not come up with a simpler plan. I was taught to compare (1) means and (2) variances, in hypothesis testing, but what about (3) the probability of falling within a specific range?

Thanks for your attention.

---

**EDIT:**

Updated method:

> For each set of values (after taking $ln$; *NA* are omitted),
>
> 1. Calculate $\mu$, $SE_\mu$, $\sigma^2$ and $SE_{\sigma^2}$ (calculated as $\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma^4}{N-1}}$).
> 2. Simulate 10,000 sets of $\bar{x} \sim N(\mu, {SE_\mu}^2)$, $s\sim \sqrt{N(\sigma^2, {SE_{\sigma^2}}^2)}$ ($s$ was sampled until positive).
> 3. For each set of $(\bar{x}, s)$, calculate $P(1 \sim 4)=P(\frac{ln(1)-\bar{x}}{s}\le z \le \frac{ln(4)-\bar{x}}{s})$.
> 4. The distribution of the simulated $P(1 \sim 4)$ values is regarded as the sampling distribution of $P(1 \sim 4)$.
>
> The two sampling distributions of $P(1 \sim 4)$ were compared directly to estimate the *p*-value.

The resultant *p*-value is 0.283, not really significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to test if their probabilities of falling within 1 and 4 are significantly different.

If all you are interested in is this, then I would not impose a distributional assumption such as log-normality. Instead, I would create a contingency table and test this.

```
> dataset <- rbind(
>   table(cut(LCp,breaks=c(1,4,Inf))),
>   table(cut(HCp,breaks=c(1,4,Inf))))
> rownames(dataset) <- c("LCp","HCp")

> dataset

    (1,4] (4,Inf]
LCp    22       2
HCp    17       7

> fisher.test(dataset)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  dataset
p-value = 0.1365
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.7127489 48.6314161
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  4.393265
```

Note that all your data are $\geq 1$, so we don't need a bucket $[-\infty,1]$. I am using [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_exact_test) since your counts are pretty low, but a $\chi^2$ test yields pretty much the same result:

```
> chisq.test(dataset)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  dataset
X-squared = 2.188, df = 1, p-value = 0.1391
```

And I find a plot quite enlightening. For one, it shows that `HCp` is systematically larger than `LCp`. So I'm not sure whether a test whether both fall in the interval $[1,4]$ is really what you want. It will depend on what you need the result for.

```
plot(LCp,HCp,xlim=range(c(LCp,HCp),na.rm=TRUE),ylim=range(c(LCp,HCp),na.rm=TRUE))
abline(0,1)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Since $P(within 1~4)$ is the ultimate parameter of concern, that is why I came up with the wish to test for this parameter. I did go for the $\chi^2$ test as well. Though, with either $\chi^2$-test or simulation method ($p=0.283$), so far I did not see any statistically significant difference. Meanwhile, as you mentioned, $HCp$ is systematically larger than $LCp$, this might be the only thing I can argue on then. All in all, that is a fair solution above. Thanks.